# How to add delay when using .just() operator

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I coded an Observable with the .just() operator as shown below in the code.
what I am trxing to do is, to add a delay to the operator so that before the Integer value is emitted to the observer it should be delayed for feew seconds

something like:

```
mAsyncObservable = rx.Observable.create(new rx.Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integr> subscriber) {
            SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            subscriber.onNext(10);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
```

How to convert the same code using .just() operator?

**code**:

```
Subscriber<Integer> integerSubscriber = new Subscriber<Integer>() {
    private final String SubscriberTag = "integerSubscriber";
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.w(TAG, "onStart->" + SubscriberTag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCompleted->" + SubscriberTag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onError->" + SubscriberTag + e.getMessage().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onNext->" + SubscriberTag + "after processing " + i);
    }
};

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    rx.Observable<Integer> integerObservable = rx.Observable.just(10);
    integerObservable.subscribe(integerSubscriber);
}
```

Comment: There is a `delay` operator for that exact purpose.

Comment: What's wrong with the `delay` operator? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html

Comment: @akarnokd would you please provide an example..i posted this question because I am new ro rxandroid i am learning it..thanks

Comment: @MarkKeen would you please provide a n example

Comment: `Observable.just(1, 2, 3).delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(() -> System.out.println("delayed number: " + integer));` - off top my head .. Google it!

Comment: As a newcommer, your first task is to learn to locate operators, which is quite easy as any decent IDE will bring up a list of them once you hit dot on your keyboard after typing `Observable.just(10)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use that:

```
Observable.just("Some").delay(1, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

But remember, that `delay()` moves Observable's execution to another thread, so you should call following code if you want to perform some UI changes after delay:

```
 Observable.just("Some").delay(1, TimeUnit.SECOND).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

**EDIT**

As @PPartisan said, you can also specify scheduler by passing it as third parameter to `delay`:

```
Observable.just("Some").delay(1, TimeUnit.SECOND, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: `delay()` also takes a 3rd argument where you can specify the `Scheduler`, so you could also write `Observable.just("some").delay(1, TimeUnit.SECOND, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread);`

Comment: i did as you provide in you answer as follows:rx.Observable<Integer> integerObservable = rx.Observable.just(2,3,4,5,8,66)
                .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        integerObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        integerObservable.subscribe(integerSubscriber);   but when I run the code i get the followiing error:onError->integerSubscriberOnly the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @user2121 you should call delay(...).observeOn( ..) (to tell java to call observeOn right after delay will be completed). Or, as I said in edit, you can pass scheduler exactly to delay() call as 3d param